# PlayFramework causes a 502 Bad gateway on long running request

Tags: http, playframework, timeout, bad-gateway

I have a long-running request, which I want to handle in Play Framework which is behind an Nginx reverse proxy.

After about 3 minutes, I get a 502 Bad Gateway as a response. Play keeps working on the request, though.

I believe the Play Framework closes the socket. I tried to set the following configurations:

In Nginx

```
proxy_read_timeout 15m;
proxy_connect_timeout 15m;
```

In play framework's application conf:

```
play.server.http.idleTimeout = infinite
play.server.https.idleTimeout = infinite
play.server.akka.http.server.idle-timeout = infinite
play.server.akka.http.client.idle-timeout = infinite
play.server.akka.http.server.request-timeout = infinite
play.server.akka.http.client.connecting-timeout = infinite
play.server.akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-connection-lifetime = infinite
play.server.akka.http.host-connection-pool.idle-timeout = infinite
play.server.akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.idle-timeout = infinite
```

(I just added all settings that might be related and set them to infinite. Happy to throw all unrelated settings out.)

But that does not appear to change anything. After about 3 minutes I get a 502 BAd Gateway. Is there any way to keep the socket alive or is there another explanation for this behaviour?

Play Version: 2.7.2

Additional information:

I set all the values to extremely low values. All the play configuration doesn't seem to have any impact. The Nginx configurations works. So, I think it has nothing to do with those play settings.

I tried to confirm that it is actually happening in Play and not in Nginx. I took the time it takes to happen when the backend server could just start: 76 seconds. When it has to go through the get ready motions after being started (compiling, liquibase): 97 seconds. I believe that confirms that the issue is to be found in Play and not in Nginx or the frontend.